# Table name in data annotations in entity framework doesn't work.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I create a project in MVC 5 with entity framework 6. I am using code first approach. I want in one of the models define a different name for the table then the default. For that I use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotationsname space and define the class like this:

```
[Table(Name="Auditoria")]
public class AuditoriaDAL
{
    [Key]
    public int AuditoriaId { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

Running the project I get a database with a table with the name AuditoriaDALs. Why the table have this name a not the name that I define?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referencing the System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table attribute when you need to reference System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table. So either do this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Auditoria")]
public class AuditoriaDAL
{
    [Key]
    public int AuditoriaId { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

Or better yet:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...

[Table("Auditoria")]
public class AuditoriaDAL
{
    [Key]
    public int AuditoriaId { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The first solution works, the second doesn't work because if I add  `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` it doesn't recognize the [Key] annotation.

Comment: If this is EF6 (as tagged), you want your Key attribute to use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as well. Try removing "using  System.Data.Linq.Mapping" which is old. I think Linq to SQL used it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or you could just get rid or annotations use the fluent api as Iraj suggests:  modelBuilder.Entity<AuditoriaDAL>().ToTable("Auditorias").HasKey(a => a.AuditoriaId );

Answer (score 3):

you can set TableName like below :

```
public class MyContext : DBContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<AuditoriaDAL> Auditorias { get; set; }
}
```

Or in OnModelCreating :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuditoriaDAL>().ToTable("Auditorias");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The name= isn't necessary. You should try [Table("Auditoria")].

Comment: If I try that I get the following compilation error: `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments`